# How to Rate Job Interview Process

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

Today I went for job interview (I'm fresh graduate Engineer). After having some question answer, one of interviewer ask me to rate the interview process out of 10. So, my question is how to rate interview program. Is there any basic for rating such a interview recruitment process.

Comment: Rather than down voting the question, I will fell more happy if someone have leaved the comment to clarify the reason for down-voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually an interview question.  They're trying to see if you can evaluate something on subjective criteria.  Imagine that you had to 'reverse engineer' 'user experience' (UX) in order to improve it.

A good place to start is by figuring out whether your 'intake' (in which you are invited to the interview, show up at the work location, and navigate the building where you're being interviewed) contains anything confusing or ambiguous.

Then evaluate the interviewer on 'knowledge of topic' - did they ask relevant questions, did they understand your answers, did they communicate their employment objectives clearly, could they illustrate to your satisfaction how they felt you might fit in?

Then evaluate 'protocol'.  Having properly covered the relevant material, did they introduce extraneous matters that were, at least on the surface, irrelevant? Did they hit you with a curveball 'out of the blue' to test your reaction to the unexpected? Were they asking questions that seemed focused on age, gender, marital status, or other things that shouldn't have come up?

Then evaluate 'wrap up'. Did they indicate when they would get back to you, how they would do so, who you would see next if they wanted another round, or when and where you would show up for your first day?

If all of these scored high you could rate it toward the 10 end of the spectrum, if it appeared weak then you could rate it lower.  While they may initially simply want a number, be prepared to explain how you came to it.

Comment: The question could also be a trap to see how likely you are to point out problems (in some--possibly most--workplaces, pointing out problems is not seen as a good thing)

Comment: Pointing out problems and being vague about it is definitely a negative. If you didn't give full marks and can't say why, I can see why that might count against you.

Comment: @Pattinson nobody here can give you the number you should have said. Meredith is telling you how to work out a number (and explain it) yourself. The explanation is the important part of the answer you would have given in the interview

Comment: @AmyBlankenship (Concerning the trap) That's actually a really great way to find out you don't want to work there! (The real trap is to accept the offer, IMO.) For a software engineer, at least, where problem solving is the name of the game, I'd be disappointed if my co-workers and especially boss discouraged feedback.

Comment: @jpaugh Real workplaces are often disappointing in at least one way. The reality is we all need to work *somewhere* under the current economic structure, and usually that means you can't hold out for perfect.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I hear you! In my last job search, I said, "Yes" to the first offer... but, while no company or culture is perfect, I'd like to think a "good fit" will pass an hour-long interview. (If the interviewers are aware of their downsides enough not to mention them, that's at least something.) The interviewee risks as much by saying, "Yes" as the hiring manager.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the way I would approach it.

I'd say: five is average. This interview was above average in these three ways.

And then make some specific statements about what just happened between you, for example:

1. You kept me informed about what was happening throughout the process
2. We had a good give and take
3. You explained these interesting details about your company (and then list them)
4. You gave me an opportunity to talk about my passion for X (repeat whatever that is)

And then say: I'm a tough grader. I'd have to give you an eight or nine.

Comment: woow great. Thanks for listing such a interesting answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if anyone has established rates like the star system for hotels with specific requirments to meet each level. Minimum would be for them to show some courtesy and hold the interview in an appropriate and comfortable place. I heard of one place that conducted the interview in a moldy basement.

The rest could depend what you think an interview should accomplish. That gets pretty subjective. There are some companies where I knew so little about them, I put a premium on getting information about the company, people and duties for the position. In others I wanted them to learn enough about me, so they could make a hiring decision. It's not an all or nothing thing but emphasising one side or the other.

Different stages of the hiring process can be a big factor on how the interview is conducted. Most initial interviews won't rate very high unless you consider this circumstance. This is driven by who is conducting the interview. An initial HR screening type interview won't be the same as that by the direct supervisor or especially another employee at the same level (They tend to come up with the 'gotcha' trivial technical questions.).

I usually come out of most interviews oblivious to how it went, so they just get a 5 or maybe a 6/7 if I'm in a good mood.